# How can I extract certain qualified nodes from a yaml document and add to a new document using PyYAML?

Tags: python, kubernetes, openshift, pyyaml

I'm new with both Python and YAML (great with Javascript and JSON) and I need to construct a subset of a YAML file. In particular, I want to generate a .yaml file that can be used to create a new deployment in openshift/kubernetes, gleaning the needed information from running pods/deployments. The YAML file will have separate sections for PVCs, Service, and Deployment.

I need to eliminate things like status, and a lot of the metadata that is generated when new pvcs, services, and deployments are created. The steps I want to use are:

- get a list of PVC claims for a running deployment
- for each of these, generate the barebones YAML to create these PVCs
- get the yaml for the service currently attached to the target deployment
- generate the barebones YAML to create this service
- get the yaml for the target deployment
- generate the barebones YAML to create this deployment

It seems like an easy thing to do, but with my scarce experience with both Python and YAML, I can't seem to get it right. I can't even traverse all of the nodes of the YAML document and print out the qualified node names.

Edit: I know which oc/kubectl commands I need to get the YAML I need, I just need some help on taking only certain sections from those files and generating a new document by inserting those extracted sections,

Comment: Even if you don't have no or not working code, you should at least give some representative input and output YAML. In any case this is better done with `ruamel.yaml`, but then I'm a bit biased ;-)

Comment: Also consider using the Kubernetes API directly, instead of trying to manipulate the YAML.  The overall code layout will probably be fairly similar, but it will act directly on the objects in the cluster.

Comment: Your description talks about creating PVCs, then attaching them to a Deployment.  _Also_ consider using a Kubernetes StatefulSet, which includes a template for creating new PersistentVolumeClaims.  (I'd argue you shouldn't usually have a Deployment with attached PVCs.)  Finally, there are tools like Helm and Kustomize that will let you manipulate the YAML in some way at deploy time, without having to write code _per se_ to rewrite it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your python script run on environment that has kubectl?
You can try to create python script which does things like -

1. Extract the data using kubectl commands using jsonpath filters; storing key information in variables
2. Create Kubernetes deployment imperative commands passing relevant parameters and generating a source yaml with --dry-run=client and -oyaml
   This will ensure a proper kubernetes compliant yaml is generated.
3. Execute the yaml using python script.

P.S. These ideas might make things simple.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea. If I read you correctly, do everything in JSON and then convert to YAML with a dry run?

Comment: That could be done as well using one of the python libraries. But the initial steps try extracting information by running raw kubectl commands with jsonpath.